# Matching data attributes, hide the rest

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following to show a corresponding div when a button is clicked, if the data attributes match. How can I hide all the others that don't match?

```
$('.document-container').click(function() {
    var myEm = $(this).data('language');
    $('.documents[data-document = '+myEm+']').show();  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `hide()` on all the elements, then `filter()` to find the ones to `show()`. Something like this:

```
$('.document-container').click(function() {
  var myEm = $(this).data('language');
  $('.documents').hide().filter('[data-document="' + myEm + '"]').show();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.document-container').click(function() {
    var myEm = $(this).data('language');
    $(".documents[data-document = '" + myEm + "']").show();  
});
```

Comment: What have you changed? *Edit* - ah I saw it, the quotes. That won't affect the issue the OP is attempting to solve though.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "Hide everything which is not what I want to show", just like this :

```
$("*:not('#divToShow')").hide();
```

I made you a Jsfiddle to try it : https://jsfiddle.net/Flyout/5qf2vadx/